# The best solution for migration-ecosystem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, database-migration

We have infrastructure which contains about 30 host for 10 microservices and 4 hosts for databases ( SQL (PostgreSQL) and NoSQL (Cassandra, Riak, Neo4j), replicated and sharded ). Periodically we need to modify DB-structure (add some tables, fields and trigers).

For some time we was using python scripts for making migrations/patches to DBs (and propogate these changes to isolated develop/analytic clusters). Next, we moved to Rails migrations. Rails is the better way (a little higher-level) for our migrations (in opposite to python scripts), but in same cases (DB specific patches, like creating postgres trigers, scharding) it requires sql commands (no-DSL).

Our purpose is to go to high-level approach for migrations (generating), like IDE (PgAdmin, DataGrip or some similar), which could:

- generate migrations/patches for DBs (which could be applied to DB cluster).
- the generated migrations/patches must be sequenced (like in Rails).
- it would be good to have the approach for SQL and NoSQL migrations/patches.

And after generating these migrations/paches we need to apply it (from commad line, CLI) on the cluster side.

There is also very specific actions for making virtual connections between some table in NoSQL and Relational DB.

So, is there any solutions for deploying such migration-ecosystem?
How do you solve such problem in you projects?